# NFC tag not detected on iOS11 iphone 7

Tags: ios, nfc, ios11

I have downloaded sample app from WWDC and tried all the steps including provisioning profile and setting up NFC capabilities and adding to project entitlements file. I can successfully ran the app and the sheet successfully appear

[image: here]

But When I tapped on one of my NFC tag. Nothing happens. How can i go further testing for NFC and may I know which one tag do I need to use to be detectable. 
Please see my attached NFC tag which I am using currently.

[image: NFC]

Answer (score 1):

iOS11 currently only detects NDEF formatted tags. So you shoould make sure that your tag is actually formatted correctly. Easiest way would be to use an Android Phone and NFC TagInfo.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I already downloaded android app to write something to NFC Tag with NDEF formatted. still no luck yet. :(

Answer (score 1):

I use Sony Xperia NFC Xperia SmartTags, it reads without problems:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will buy that one and try again. We need to write something into NFC tags right? so that it can detect.